# Excel formulas for calculating total numbers in different worksheets, calculating total number of given strings in worksheets

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

We have a rather large spreadsheet that we use to store information about various different things.

Within this workbook we would have multiple sheets, which could store 100s or 1000s of different entries, which, as you imagine, would be rather complicated and a lengthy process to get exact data from.

What I would like to know is whether it is possible to have formulas that tell you different things (**all of the below spreadsheets are intended to be separate from the one holding the statistical information**) -

1) How many total users there are across multiple worksheets

2) How many total users there are in a single worksheet.

3) How many total users have entered in a given string, like, for example, how many people have specified their location as "New York", how many as "London", etc.

4) Optional - how many people have specific they are 30 or less (based on DOB)

**The end goal would be that we would have either a single or multiple sheet that would have all the statistical information in it and that these would be updated automatically when we add more to the spreadsheet.**

We're working on a better system, but just right now what we have is Excel, so I would just like to make this more user friendly.

So my question is - are the above formulas possible and, if so, how would I go about doing them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a formula that uses cells from different sheets you should write the name of the sheet followed by a '!' and then comes the cell. 
So if you want to add the value from cell A1 in Sheet1 to the value of cell A1 in Shhet2 this is you're formula: 
=Sheet1!A1+Sheet2!A1